# setOnItemSelectedListener does not work, problems with focus ListView

Tags: android, listview

I try to set the focus on ListView but onItemSelected - not work, here is my source

```
uAdapter = new UrlArrayAdapter(DatabaseTable.this, urlListView,
                urlLists);
        urlListView.setAdapter(uAdapter);
    urlListView.setItemsCanFocus(true);
        urlListView.setClickable(false);
        urlListView.setOnItemSelectedListener(new OnItemSelectedListener() {
        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int pos,
                long id) {  });
```

I use the following XML. My LisWiev xml

```
    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/listView1"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:descendantFocusability="beforeDescendants" >
    </ListView>
```

and an item xml which add to the ListView

```
    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/editLinearLayout1"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:minHeight="50dp" >
        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/editText1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="0.66"
            android:ems="10" >
            <requestFocus />
        </EditText>
        <CheckBox
            android:id="@+id/checkBox1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:focusable="false"
            android:focusableInTouchMode="false" />
    </LinearLayout>
```

I solved the problem, helped me this article, it is shown how to use the ListView 
[Linc] (`http://www.lalit3686.blogspot.in/2012/06/today-i-am-going-to-show-how-to-deal.html`)

and **Helped me to this link**
`http://vikaskanani.wordpress.com/2011/07/27/android-focusable-edittext-inside-listview/`

Comment: `onItemSelected` is not called? Try removing focus from EditText also as you did for CheckBox.

Comment: made the focus was lost but onItemSelected is not called

Comment: try urlListView.setClickable(true);

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your onItemSelected is not being called, since you have set the `setClickable` attibute of your list to false. Try changing it to true and then check out. I hope that will work.

Comment: not called, in one case only worked When I'm in the method getView (extends ArrayAdapter) setting the listener on the item

Comment: Plz provide more details regarding your query.. Also paste your LogCat if there is any kind of error in your activity..

Comment: I do not know how explained to, I need to see an example where there is a working Listener